# Finding tag of text-searched element in HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape multiple web pages to compare the prices of books. Because every site has a different layout (and class names), I want to find the title of the book using regex and then the surrounding elements. An example of the code is given below.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_page1 = """
<div class='product-box'>
<h2 class='title'>Title Book</h2>
<p class='price>18.45</p>
</div>
"""

html_page2 = """
<div class='page-box'>
<h2 class='orange-heading'>Title Book</h2>
<p class='blue-price'>18.45</p>
</div>
"""

# turn page into soup
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html_page1, 'html.parser')

# find book titles
names1 = soup1.find_all(string=re.compile("[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+)(?:\s{1}[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+))"))

# print titles
print('Names1: ', names1)

# turn page into soup
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_page2, 'html.parser')

# find book titles
names2 = soup2.find_all(string=re.compile("[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+)(?:\s{1}[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+))"))

# print titles
print('Names2: ', names2)
```

This returns:

```
Names1:  ['Title Book']
Names2:  ['Title Book']
```

Now I want to use this information to find the corresponding price. I know that when an element has been selected using the tags and class names, "next_sibling" can be used, however this doesn't work for the element selected by text:

```py
select_title = soup1.find('h2', {"class": "title"})
next_sib = new_try.next_sibling
print(next_sib) # returns <p class='price>18.45

# now try the same thing on element selected by name, this will result in an error
next_sib = names1.next_sibling
```

How can I use the same method to find the price when I have found the element using its text?

A similiar question can be found here: [Find data within HTML tags using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54045382/find-data-within-html-tags-using-python) However, it still uses the html tags.

**EDIT** The problem is that I have many pages with different layouts and class names. Because of that I cannot use the tag/class/id name to find the elements and I have to find the book titles using regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the price Include 'h2' tag while doing it `find_all`() And then use `find_next`('p')
The first example of p tag where string was missing for classname I have added the string `class='price'`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_page1 = """
<div class='product-box'>
<h2 class='title'>Title Book</h2>
<p class='price'>18.45</p>
</div>
"""

html_page2 = """
<div class='page-box'>
<h2 class='orange-heading'>Title Book</h2>
<p class='blue-price'>18.45</p>
</div>
"""


# turn page into soup
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html_page1, 'html.parser')

# find book titles
names1 = soup1.find_all('h2',string=re.compile("[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+)(?:\s{1}[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+))"))

# print titles
print('Names1: ', names1[0].find_next('p').text)


# turn page into soup
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_page2, 'html.parser')

# find book titles
names2 = soup2.find_all('h2',string=re.compile("[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+)(?:\s{1}[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+))"))

# print titles
print('Names2: ', names2[0].find_next('p').text)
```

---

Or change string to text

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_page1 = """
<div class='product-box'>
<h2 class='title'>Title Book</h2>
<p class='price'>18.45</p>
</div>
"""

html_page2 = """
<div class='page-box'>
<h2 class='orange-heading'>Title Book</h2>
<p class='blue-price'>18.45</p>
</div>
"""


# turn page into soup
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html_page1, 'html.parser')

# find book titles
names1 = soup1.find_all(text=re.compile("[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+)(?:\s{1}[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+))"))

# print titles
print('Names1: ', names1[0].find_next('p').text)


# turn page into soup
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_page2, 'html.parser')

# find book titles
names2 = soup2.find_all(text=re.compile("[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+)(?:\s{1}[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+))"))

# print titles
print('Names2: ', names2[0].find_next('p').text)
```

---

**EDITED**
Use text to get the element without tag and next_element to get the value of price.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_page1 = """
<div class='product-box'>
<h2 class='title'>Title Book</h2>
<p class='price'>18.45</p>
</div>
"""

html_page2 = """
<div class='page-box'>
<h2 class='orange-heading'>Title Book</h2>
<p class='blue-price'>18.45</p>
</div>
"""

# turn page into soup
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html_page1, 'html.parser')
# find book titles
names1 = soup1.find_all(text=re.compile("[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+)(?:\s{1}[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+))"))
# print titles
print('Names1: ', names1[0])
print('Price1: ', names1[0].next_element.next_element.next_element)
# turn page into soup
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_page2, 'html.parser')
# find book titles
names2 = soup2.find_all(text=re.compile("[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+)(?:\s{1}[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+))"))
# print titles
print('Names2: ', names2[0])
print('Price2: ', names2[0].next_element.next_element.next_element)
```

**Output**:

```
Names1:  Title Book
Price1:  18.45
Names2:  Title Book
Price2:  18.45
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is however that I have many more pages with different layouts so I cannot use the class or tag names to find the elements or the siblings. I have edited my question to make this clear.

Comment: @Hav11 : Check the edited answer.I believe this is what you after without any tag?

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain why you have to call 'next_element' three times? Because calling it just once seems to return an empty string.

Comment: @Hav11 : The first next_element will find after </tag> of the title then next_element  will find the start <tag> of price element and then next_element  will find the value of price.

Answer (score 0):

You missed class closure comma for the `p.price` in `html_page1`.
With `names1 = soup1.find_all(text=re.compile("[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+)(?:\s{1}[A-Z]([a-z]+,|\.|[a-z]+))"))` you get `NavigableString`, that's why you'll get `None` for the `next_sibling`.

You can find solution with regex in @Kunduk answer.
Alternative more clear and simple solution for the both `html_page1` and `html_page2`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page1, 'html.parser')
# or BeautifulSoup(html_page2, 'html.parser')

books = soup.select('div[class*=box]')
for book in books:
    book_title = book.select_one('h2').text
    book_price = book.select_one('p[class*=price]').text
    print(book_title, book_price)
```

`div[class*=box]` mean **div** where class contains **box**.

Comment: Unfortunately both options didn't work, ```next_sib = None```, and because of that it doesn't have an attribute .text.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer! The problem is however, that this is just a small example and there are other pages where the class name does not contain 'box'. I want to find the elements with the products in it without using any tag or class name. I will make this more clear in my question.